# Is there any simple option to convert csv file to JSONL file?

Tags: csv

I have a dataset having 6000 records in csv file format type which I would like to convert it into  JSONL(json line) format. I am not able to find any simple way of accomplishing my objective. Any lead will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Node.js ??

Comment: no, I m looking for a tool/library to let me achieve that

Answer (score 2):

In example starting from

```
nome,dataNascita,altezza,peso
andy,1973-05-08,176,86.5
chiara,1993-12-13,162,58.3
guido,2001-01-22,196,90.4
```

And using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), you can run

```
mlr --c2j cat input.csv >output.jsonl
```

to have

```json
{ "nome": "andy", "dataNascita": "1973-05-08", "altezza": 176, "peso": 86.5 }
{ "nome": "chiara", "dataNascita": "1993-12-13", "altezza": 162, "peso": 58.3 }
{ "nome": "guido", "dataNascita": "2001-01-22", "altezza": 196, "peso": 90.4 }
```

---

**Note**: I have written this answer in 2021 and **I used Miller 5**, in which the default json output was jsonlines.

To have this kind of output in **Miller 6** you can edit the command in this way, in which I set input and output format:

```
mlr --icsv --ojsonl cat input.csv
```

Comment: This worked great for me. However, this writes to file as a json array. To write as jsonl, I piped the output to jq, so, the final command is `mlr --c2j cat input.csv | jq -c '.[]' >output.jsonl`

Comment: hi @Sundeep this is a 2021 answer and I used the older version of Miller (5 version), in wich the default json output was jsonlines. Now it's json. To have jsonlines in version 6 you can run `mlrgo --icsv --ojsonl cat input.csv`